# spring boot oauth2 configuration: resource server remains unprotected

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have implemented authorization server and resource server using spring boot. authorization server works fine and I am able to get tokens. But my resource server remains unprotected. My objective is that resource server ahould only be accessed by someone having valid access token.

My entire code is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore)
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient("client")
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
            .secret("secret")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(180)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(600);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        super.configure(security); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources
                .tokenServices(tokenServices())
                .resourceId("MY_RESOURCE");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .anonymous().disable()
                .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/**")
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").access("hasRole('USER')")
                    .antMatchers("/secure/").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
        final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
```

### }

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("ADMIN").and()
        .withUser("bob").password("abc123").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll();
    }
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}
```

---

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> hello(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello World");
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/secure/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> secure(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Secure Resorce");
    }
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }
```

### }

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>boot-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>boot-oauth2</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins> 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What am I missing? 
Thanks for help.

**UPDATE:**
I figured out that my resource server is unprotected because of presence of `OAuth2SecurityConfig` class. If I remove this class and add following class (where I have moved the inMemmory users), then resource server is protected as required

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityGlobalConfig extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("bill").password("abc123").roles("ADMIN").and()
        .withUser("bob").password("abc123").roles("USER");
    }

}
```

So, I am sensing improper HttpSecurity configuration in OAuth2SecurityConfig class is conflicting with resource server config. 
So, How can I configure HttpSecurity of OAuth2SecurityConfig so, that it does allow access token protection for resource server paths and normal web security for non-resource server paths

Comment: Everything is in the same app or separately?

Comment: Everything in one app only

Answer (score 8, accepted):

finally after a lot of googling, I found the solution.

It was due to order of filters. order of OAuth2 resource filter has been changed in spring-boot-1.5.1. as change log says

> The default order of the OAuth2 resource filter has changed from 3 to
>   SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER - 1. This places it after the
>   actuator endpoints but before the basic authentication filter chain.
>   The default can be restored by setting
>   security.oauth2.resource.filter-order = 3

So, I changed the order of my OAuth2 resource server filter to 3 by setting it in application.properties `security.oauth2.resource.filter-order = 3` and my problem was solved.

Comment: Thanks, saved me a lot of time!

Comment: this property has been removed in boot 2.x. Any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your OAuth2SecurityConfig with @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I had another class extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter that i guess was in conflict with AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter.

I just **removed the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter** class and it worked.